# PHP print out specific html content from string

Tags: php, html, string, printing

Hi i have a string that includes html content. I need to print it out from printer.

For example, my string is;

```
$string =" 
<html>
<head>
<style type='text/css'>
 //CSS COMES HERE
</style>
</head>
<body>
Hello world
</body>
</html>";
```

i need to print that strings output. For eg;

```
Printer.Print(echo '$string');
```

//There is no such a command i just want to explain what im trying to do.

Comment: echo $string =" <style type='text/css'>
body{ background-color:#069}
</style>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
Hello world
</body>
</html>";

Comment: There is some internal and inline css in string if it is your point?

Comment: you have to set header for printing html content

Comment: "Hello world"  comes to the screen. How can i print it out from printer without seeing in screen?

Comment: like what? @SagarPanchal